# calendar.isLenient() isn't functioning

Tags: java, android, calendar

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html), a lenient calendar can convert a date that surpasses the end of a year into a date of the next year:

> When a Calendar is lenient, it accepts a wider range of field values than it produces. For example, a lenient GregorianCalendar interprets MONTH == JANUARY, DAY_OF_MONTH == 32 as February 1.

But I'm not getting it to work, I'm scheduling a PendingIntent to get called in 3 weeks, and it works fine all year until week 52 comes, it gets called immediatelly instead of in 3 weeks

```
Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SATURDAY);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 13);
    calendar.isLenient();
    calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, currentCal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) + 2);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try printing the date after the last set? That can easily show you if the calendar is being set properly. In my quick test everything works fine. Maybe it will point to the problem inside the scheduler that executes the event.

Comment: Have a look at the javaDocs for the `set` methods - it stats that `The value is not interpreted by this method regardless of the leniency mode.`  Try using in conjunction with the `clear` method(s)

Comment: So it randomly just started working, the `isLenient()` was literally not working, thanks anyway =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone faces this issue try rebuilding the project, delete the app from your phone and run it again, worked for me!